# SQL Server 7.0 - Finding the tables and the columns for a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server

For a given database, I want to know which tables and which columns have a certain value.
I am using this Stored Procedure (modified from [here](http://sandeep-tada.blogspot.pt/2013/07/sql-server-how-to-find-value-in-all.html)), which I'm not sure it is correct since I still haven't found what is the equivalent to sys.Tables and sys.Schemas in SQL Server 7.0. And there is very little documentation for this version.

Thank you in advance.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchFromAllTables 
@searchValue VARCHAR(256)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @searchQuery VARCHAR(1024)
SET @searchQuery = ''

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempResults') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.#TempResults
END

CREATE TABLE dbo.#TempResults
       ([TableName] VARCHAR(128),
       [ColumnName] VARCHAR(128),
       [ColumnValue] VARCHAR(512))

SELECT @searchQuery = 'SELECT ''' + S.name + '.' + T.name
        + ''' AS [TableName], ''' + C.name
        + ''' AS [ColumnName], CAST(' + QUOTENAME(C.name)
        + 'AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [ColumnValue] FROM '
        + QUOTENAME(S.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.name) +
        ' (NOLOCK) WHERE CAST(' + QUOTENAME(C.name)
        + ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE ' + '''%'
        + @searchValue + ' %'''
FROM sys.Schemas S
INNER JOIN sys.Tables T ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
INNER JOIN syscolumns C ON T.object_id = C.object_id
INNER JOIN systypes TY ON C.system_type_id = TY.system_type_id
            AND C.user_type_id = TY.user_type_id
WHERE T.is_ms_shipped = 0
AND TY.name NOT IN ('timestamp', 'image', 'sql_variant')
    INSERT dbo.#TempResults
EXEC sp_executesql @searchQuery
SELECT [TableName], [ColumnName], [ColumnValue] FROM dbo.#TempResults
END
```

Comment: SQL 7??? Seriously??? I haven't touched that in 15+ years. You will have to use sysobjects where type = 'u' for tables. I don't remember how to find schemas at all.

Comment: @SeanLange I know, unfortunatelly it's what I have to work with. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funnily enough that looks like an updated version of an ancient script I remember coming across years ago.

The original version is [still online here](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm).

It states it's tested in SQL Server 7.0 and uses `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. The metadata views you are using and `max` datatypes certainly won't work pre 2005 versions.